# Repeated file appending fills up memory in PHP

Tags: php

I have a system that reads in some data, parses it and geolocates it before appending it to a file. However, when I set it running it fills up the memory on the virtual machine I'm running it on and eventually crashes. Is there something that I should be doing to prevent this from happening?

```
$incident = "";

file_put_contents("incidents.txt", ""); // Wipe existing incidents file for rewriting

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof(data); $i++) {
    $address = geocode($data[$i][13]); // Geocode address
    if ($address) { // If address geocoded correctly

        // Write out data in specified JSON format
        $incident = "{\"crime_type\": \"{$data[$i][9]}\"," .
                      "\"time\": \"{$data[$i][11]}\"," .
                      "\"lat\": \"{$address[0]}\"," .
                      "\"lng\": \"{$address[1]}\"," .
                      "\"date\": {$data[$i][10]}}";
        if ($i < sizeof($data) - 1) { // If not last entry
            $incident = $incident . "|"; // Add delimiter
        }
        file_put_contents("incidents.txt", $incident, FILE_APPEND); // Append new incident to incidents file
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the geocode function doing?

Comment: file_put_contents calls fopen(), fwrite() and fclose(), so you basically open your file sizeof(data) times. Could be that instances to the file get not cleaned up properly from garbage collector. I would suggest to open the file before the for loop, and closing it afterwards to prevend opening it to many times.

Comment: `$incident = $incident . "|";` is just growing and growing in your loop: it's never reset, even when you write it to file, so it's going to take moer and more memory every iteration of the loop

Comment: @MarkBaker I think you are wrong `$incident` reset in each loop when `$incident = "{\"crime_type\": \"{$data[$i][9]}\","...` so there is no problem with memory holding `$incident` I would prefer agree with @mondjunge comment.

Comment: @Halfstop It's simply an API call that parses in the response data and returns a latitude/longitude for the address. I'll post code if you think it would help.

Comment: @mondjunge Wouldn't that mean that the entire file has to be read into memory at one time? Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @user3893820 I am not sure, but php is not very strict language in memory usage perspective. so this loop can open 100, 1000 or 10 000 file instances during the loop without clear memory after it had been used.

Comment: good question I have no answer to this. Try opening a 1GB Text file with PHP on a local apache and see how the memory consumption rises. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mondjunge mentioned you should better avoid to use `file_put_contents`,

try this way:

```
$incident = "";

$file = fopen("incidents.txt", 'a+'); // Wipe existing incidents file for rewriting

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof(data); $i++) {
    $address = geocode($data[$i][13]); // Geocode address
    if ($address) { // If address geocoded correctly

        // Write out data in specified JSON format
        $incident = "{\"crime_type\": \"{$data[$i][9]}\"," .
                      "\"time\": \"{$data[$i][11]}\"," .
                      "\"lat\": \"{$address[0]}\"," .
                      "\"lng\": \"{$address[1]}\"," .
                      "\"date\": {$data[$i][10]}}";
        if ($i < sizeof($data) - 1) { // If not last entry
            $incident = $incident . "|"; // Add delimiter
        }
        fwrite($file, $incident); // Append new incident to incidents file
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: I'm giving that a run now, I'll tell you whether it works or not.

Comment: exactly how I meant it. Should, at least, avoid potential flaws in file_put_content function and/or php garbage collector.

Comment: @user3893820 so did you check the memory usage? does it help?

Comment: Worked great, thanks. Memory jumped up a fair way but didn't fill up like before so I guess it had to read the file into memory before working on it.